# Derivative of a function at a point using limit notation confusion. Please Help

Tags: calculus, limits

So I understand that taking a derivative of a function at a point $x$ using limits is
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h}$$ where $h$ approaches zero from both negative and positive side.

I know the positive side approach but I am confused about the negative side. When h approaches zero from the negative side, should we substitute $h$ as $-h$ in the difference quotient, if not then what's the difference between the two limits. If we evaluate both of them as it is , we will always get the same answer for both the approaches, making every function differentiable at every point.

Comment: There is no need to substitute $h \mapsto -h$ in the difference quotient, unless you want $h \to 0^+$. The difference in $y$-values is still $f(x+h)$ and the difference in $x$-values is still $h$, even if $h$ is negative.

Comment: See [this website](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/Math/Precalculus_obj/moreDiffQuot.htm) for diagrams for when $h$ is positive and negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint: The difference is not in the formula, but the value that the variable h here approaches to.**
I will give you an example here.
**Example:**
I choose $f(x)$ to be $|x|$, then I want to find the both the left limit and the right limit st $x=0$.
So the left limit would be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Leftlimit&=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{|h|}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{-h}{h}\\
&=-1
\end{aligned}
$$
So the right limit would be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Rightlimit&=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{|h|}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{h}{h}\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
$$
So you see that it will be different sometimes.
**My Guess**
I think you feel confused because it is really most functions we are working with now are differentiable, this means their left and right limit at every point is the same, and it makes you feeling that they are always the same.
*I hope it will help.*

Comment: Why did you substitute h as -h only in the numerator and not in the denominator. Thats where I am confused. I asked Chat GPT and it said that we shouldn't substitute h as -h when h is approaching 0 from the negative side because the limit notation already makes it clear.So if h remains the same, then both the limits would also evaluate to a same answer always

Comment: It is not substitution, it is because the example function here have this kind of property, thank you for reminding, I will make my answer more complete, then you can find the reason from it.

Comment: It is edited again now.

Comment: Okay, last question. Can you give me an example of a function with a sharp turn or cusp or both. A function which is not differentiable at all the points. Just give me the function, no need to find its derivative

Comment: Dirichlet function I suggest.

Comment: But Dirichlet function doesn't have a sharp turn or a cusp

Comment: But it is not differentiable for all the x

Answer (score -1):

I would disagree that if we approach zero from positive and negative sides, then we will always get the same value of the derivative. Consider a function like $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. It increases on the positive side of zero and decreases on the negative side. So the limit will approach different value on the positive and negative side, so the function is non-differentiable. You can verify it yourself by plugging in some values near zero on the positive and negative side in the limit.

Comment: That function is obviously not differentiable at the origin, since it's not even *defined* there to begin with... (That is, you can't even form the expression $(f(h)-f(0))/h$ that you're supposed to take the limit of.)